# Animated Views blocking other activity' components

Tags: android, animation, view

I have created few views and tryied to use `TranslateAnimation` to make them appear/disappear from the bottom of the screen. 
the animations work fine but the problem is that they block buttons existing on the activity where i called my views and the other views themselves(since the animate on same area).
i tryed to bring each view to front when appearing but this only solved the problem between the view and not the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this by using Popupwindow.